# Value incorrect Recursion

Tags: java, binary, type-conversion

I have a little problem with my function, the function does the conversion of decimal to binary but I print the value backwards for example the following code:

I pass the `28` to binary that would have to be `0000011100` but I return `0011100000`

```
public void binary(int n, char[] array, int bits) {

    if (0 == n) {
        return;
    }

    int temporal = n;
    n = n / 2;

    if (temporal % 2 == 0) {
        array[array.length - (bits--)] = '0';
    } else {
        array[array.length - (bits--)] = '1';
    }

    binary(n, array, bits);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you currently call the method as follows:

```
int n = 28;  // Decimal value
int bits = 10;   // Size of the binary result
char[] array = new char[bits];
for (int i=0; i<bits; i++)  // Initialize to zeroes
    array[i] = '0';
binary(n, array, bits);   // Start the recursion
```

Which creates:

```
0011100000
```

To get your desired result, bits should increment from 0 (as you are iterating from the low bit towards the high bit in your algorithm).

So start the recursion like this:

```
binary(n, array, 0);   // Start the recursion
```

And increment `bits` as follows:

```
if (temporal % 2 == 0) { 
    array[array.length-(bits++)-1]='0';
}
else {
    array[array.length-(bits++)-1]='1';
}
```

Which creates:

```
0000011100
```

**EDIT**:  Change to allow bits to start at max size

```
public static void binary(int n, char [] array, int bits) {

    if(0 == n) { 
        return ;
    }

    int temporal = n;
    n = n/2;

    if (temporal % 2 == 0) { 
        array[bits-1]='0';
    }

    else {
        array[bits-1]='1';
    }

    binary(n, array, bits-1);
}
```

Comment: Correct the method is the one you indicate, but I'm interested in the variable bits being 10 i not 0, some alternative?

Comment: public void inici() {
        int n = 28;
        char[] array = new char[]{'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'};
        int bits = 10;
        binary(n, array, bits);        System.out.println(arrayBin);    }

Comment: Yes.  Please see revised answer

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Ian!